# Own ORM and data redundancy when mapping multiple tables into one object

Tags: database, design-patterns, orm, jdbc

Firstly, sorry for my English.

This is my first time playing with databases in Java and I want to write a simple middle-layer (between database and application) in pure JDBC and SQL which will map my tables onto objects (and vice versa). I have read a little about DAOs, ORMs and Active Record pattern and one thing bothers me a lot: How this systems deal with data redundancy when populating an object which consist of multiple tables?

For example:

I have two tables

```
TABLE message (id, content, recipient_id)
TABLE person (id, name, address)
```

which I want to be mapped onto

```java
/* depends on message and person tables */
class Message
{
    public Message(int id, String content, Person recipient) {...}
    // setters, getters ommited.
    private int id;
    private String content;
    private Person recipient;
}

/* depends on person table */
class Person
{
    public Person(int id, String name, String address) {...}
    // setters, getters ommited.
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
}
```

I see two solutions:

1) I can map `table message` onto object `Message` by performing SQL select joining these two tables on `message.recipient_id = person.id`. Corresponding objects will be populated with `new Message(..., new Person(...))`. This will of course leave me with lots of duplicated data as long as there is 'one-to-many' relationship between person and message.

2) I can select everything from `table person`, populate objects with `new Person(...)` and store them in `Map<Integer, Person>` (map key will hold id's). Then select everything from `table message` and manually 'join' these two by finding matching `Person`. This will leave me with one instance of `Person` referenced by multiple `Message`'s but I'm affraid the whole point of keeping data in a database is lost in that case.

How ORM systems deal with that? What should I do in that situation?

Comment: Just suggestion: isn't it better to get ready-to-use ORM? Take a look at Ebean - www.avaje.org - it's lightweight, customizable and fast.